# Why collisions are necessary for electrical conductivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, collision

I have a simple question that came to my mind studying the semiclassical electron dynamics: why there must be collisions between particles to have conductivity? If it’s not necessary, what’s the fundamental mechanism driving it?

Comment: Did you mean resistivity instead of conductivity?

Comment: They are not. For example, in a vacuum tube you can have electrical conduction without collisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current $J=\sigma E$. But more fundamentally $j=-env$ where e is the charge, n is the number of electrons per unity volume and $v$ is the velocity of the charge. So can have currents without collisions (ballistic transport) but in almost any case if you are talking about a material - unless looking at transport over very short distances - it is convenient to think about the electrons as gas of particles with very high velocity (fermi sphere) and without an applied field there is no net current.

If you apply an electric field the electrons will have a directional force due to the field and accelerate for some mean time between the collisions with some mean free path. This shifts the fermi sphere is the drift velocity with some net motion of the electrons giving a current.

> [Consider](https://unlcms.unl.edu/cas/physics/tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/Section%2008_Electron_Transport.pdf) a typical electron at time zero. Let t be the time elapsed since its last collision. Its velocity at time zero will be its velocity v0 immediately after that collision plus the additional velocity
> −eEt/m it has subsequently acquired. Since we assume that an electron emerges from a collision in a random direction, there will be no contribution from v0 to the average electronic velocity, which must therefore be given entirely by the average of −eEt/m. However, the average of t is the relaxation time τ.

So by substituting in the expression for the velocity you get

$\sigma = \frac{-ne^2\tau}{m}$

that relates the current to the applied electric field, but now has a term that is for the mass of the electron and the mean time between collisions.

So why do we care?

We didn't have to say anything about the details of the scattering or why the collisions occurred. If we get into the details there could be different times for different types of collisions but we can wrap them up into a mean collision time. $\frac{1}{\tau_{total}}=\frac{1}{\tau_{1}}+\frac{1}{\tau_{2}}$. It also turns out that you can also define the mobility $\mu$ of the electron in terms drift velocity. $v_d=\mu E$ and with the band structure have an understanding of the how the drift velocity, effective mass and scattering are related.

Ultimately conductivity is not as fundamental as $j=-env$, but it is very convenient way to label a material property.